# How to get specific year from the Date field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I know its a bit silly question, but I actually wanted to know how can I retrieve the year value for a date that I already have without using the "Split" function. I can achieve it with the help of the "split" function. Below is the code that I used in jquery.

```js
outputJSon = JSON.parse($('#' + Datepicker_id).val());
var currentYear = parseInt(CalculateYearfromString($('#' + currentActivityCalendarId).parents('.service-timeline').find('.membership-year .period').text()));

if (currentYear === undefined && $.trim(currentYear) === "")
  currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

if (parseInt(outputJSon["Date"].split('/')[0]) === currentYear)
  outputDate = outputJSon["Date"];
else
  outputDate = outputJSon["Date"].replace(outputJSon["Date"].split('/')[0], currentYear)

outputDateType = outputJSon["DateType"];
```

In the above code, I am retrieving the date value in a JSON format which returns **Date eg. 2016/05/26** and **DateType eg. Day**.

I am fetching the current year that I have selected and then checking if **currentYear** value is equal to the year that I have in the **outputJSon["Date"]**. If there is a match, then I am replacing the **[0]** value of the **outputJSon["Date"]** with the **currentYear**, with the help of **replace** function. This works as expected and no error is encountered.

I just want to be sure that if the date format changes(**from 2016/05/26 to 26/05/2016)**then the split function that I have written will retrieve wrong value. How can I avoid this. Shall I remove **split** function and think of something else?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `myDate.getFullYear` will do that

Comment: I found the solution. thanks

Comment: do you mind sharing?

Comment: I replaced the else part with the code: **outputDate = outputJSon["Date"].replace(new Date(outputJSon["Date"]).getFullYear(), currentYear);**

Comment: @Yash—but your code has dysfunctional sections, you might consider fixing those. And parsing strings with the Date constructor is not a good idea, particularly when the date format is not standard. *currentYear* may be *NaN*.

Comment: Thank you @RobG for the heads up. I fixed the dysfunction sections code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally unsexy, but what's wrong with *indexOf*?

```
if (outputJSon["Date"].indexOf(currentYear) != -1) {
  // currentYear is in the string somewhere
}
```

Note also that in the original, there is no need for *parseInt*:

```
outputJSon["Date"].split('/')[0] == currentYear
```

is sufficient (and less to type).

Also, *parseInt* will never return *undefined*, so:

```
currentYear === undefined
```

will always be false and so:

```
if (currentYear === undefined && $.trim(currentYear) === "")
```

will never be true and the assignment:

```
  currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

will never execute.

I would also seriously question the use of:

```
outputJSon = JSON.parse($('#' + Datepicker_id).val());
```

The use of JSON.parse seems entirely gratuitous, you already have a string returned by `$('#' + Datepicker_id).val()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length to make sure it is a valid year number.

```
currentYear2 = outputJSon["Date"].split('/');
currentYear2 = (currentYear2[0].length === 4) ? currentYear2[0] : currentYear2[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any issues when you simply do

```
outputDate = new Date(outputJSon["Date"]).getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex_yearfirst = /\d{4}\W/;
regex_yearlast = /\d{4}\n/;
if (regex_yearfirst.test(outputJSon["Date"])) {
    yearIndex=0;
    }
else if (regex_yearlast.test(outputJSon["Date"])) {
    yearIndex=2;
    }
else {
    console.log("date format not recognized")
    }
if (parseInt(outputJSon["Date"].split('/')[yearIndex]) === currentYear) { 
outputDate = outputJSon["Date"]; 
    }
else {
  outputDate = outputJSon["Date"].replace(outputJSon["Date"].split('/')[yearIndex], currentYear)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/mvqv4eah/).

#### Code

```js
function getYear() {
    var input = $("#dpDate").val();
    var cdate = getDate(input);
    console.log(cdate, cdate.getFullYear());
}

function getDate(input) {
    var arr = [];
    var seperator = ['/', '-'];
    var year, month, date;
    var yearIndex = 2;
    var result = undefined;

    seperator.forEach(function(s) {
        if (input.indexOf(s) > -1)
            arr = input.split(s);
    });

    if (arr.length > 1) {
        // Set year
        if (arr[0] > 1000) {
            year = arr[0]
            yearIndex = 0;
        } else if (arr[2] > 1000) {
            year = arr[2];
            yearIndex = 2;
        }

        // set month and date
        // If string starts with year, assume yyyy/mm/dd
        if (yearIndex === 0) {
            month = arr[1]
            date = arr[2]
        } else {
            // If value greater than 12, assume it as date and other one as month
            if (arr[0] > 12) {
                date = arr[0]
                month = arr[1]
            } else if (arr[1] > 12) {
                date = arr[1]
                month = arr[0]
            }
            // If none of the value is ggreater than 12, assume default format of dd/mm/yyyy
            else {
                date = arr[0]
                month = arr[1]
            }
        }

        result = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dpDate" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="15/2/2016" />
<button onclick="getYear()">Get Year</button>
```